# How to set error_logger_hwm in the new RabbitMQ .conf configuration file format?

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

I'm troubleshooting RabbitMQ's cluster network partition events and some log messages were being dropped. The nodes run on Windows VMs. I was trying to fix the message dropping part as described [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/1471#issuecomment-357015433). Therefore, I added the following to my advanced.config file:

```
[
    {lager, [
        {error_logger_hwm, 1024}
    ]}
].
```

How do I verify that the configuration change was applied instead of just waiting to see if more messages are dropped or not?

**[UPDATE]**: On my original post I was trying to change this config in the .conf file, since that's what I'm using to configure RabbitMQ. However, the lager configuration has to be done in the advanced.config file. The advanced.config file seems to be applied even if you are using a .conf file for the basic configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set that value in `rabbitmq.conf`. The link you provide shows how to set the value in the `/etc/rabbitmq/advanced.config` file. Please carefully re-read [this comment](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/1471#issuecomment-357015433).

You can verify it by running this command:

```
rabbitmqctl eval 'application:get_env(lager, error_logger_hwm).'
```

Also see this article:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#verify-configuration-effective-configuration

Comment: Thank you for your answers @Luke, but the command you referred to throws the error: "Error (argument validation): "unterminated atom starting with 'application:get_'"
Arguments given:
        eval 'application:get_env(lager, error_logger_hwm).'

BTW, I'm using RabbitMQ 3.7.13 and Erlang 21.

**[UPDATE]**: I replace the single quotes with double ones and it worked.

Comment: I've also updated my post to correct the configuration file to be used.Thanks again @Luke.

Comment: Sorry about that, you must be using Windows

Comment: Yes. I should have said that in my post. My bad.